# LDAP commands are still working without ldap_mod enabled

Tags: apache, ldap

I've been having a problem with my (development) site hanging when I try to login using LDAP credentials.  Using xdebug, I was able to pinpoint the hang to a specific line of code, which is a call to `ldap_bind(...)`.  After days of trying to understand why it is hanging, one of my debugging techniques was to disable mod_ldap, and then just try to get any error to show up in apache log (after this has started, apache error logs haven't been recording any errors while performing this http request; It 'hangs' too).

**What I did**

I disabled the module (`sudo a2dismod mod_ldap`), restarted the server (`sudo service apache2 restart`), and confirmed that the module isn't enabled (`apache2ctl -M` does not show `mod_ldap`)

**The Problem**

It still hangs when it reaches `ldap_bind()`, however, it shouldn't even be reaching that point because without mod_ldap, my code shouldn't even be successfully calling `ldap_connect()` (right?) which is returning `(resource) resource id='5' type='ldap link'` (meaning the call was successful).  I'm expecting a NoMethod or Function error.

Why can php make a call to a module that isn't enabled, and how do I stop that behavior?

**Version**

> Ubuntu 14.04
>
> Apache 2.4.7
>
> PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out, I had a novice understanding of what was happening.  Never occurred to me that `ldap_connect()` as a php call had nothing to do with `mod_ldap` or any apache module.  Thus, disabling/enabling apache mods wasn't doing anything because... it had nothing to do with apache mods.

So... I was able to disable ldap php extension with

`sudo php5dismod ldap`

and able to check that it was disabled with

`php -m`

And sure enough, after restarting the server, running my script caused a No function error for `ldap_connect()` (just as I was expecting/hoping).  Now I just need to figure out why `ldap_bind()` hangs...